# where in field did user click?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have some text displayed on a web page (say in span element) and I have added `onclick` event and can capture the entire field when a user clicks it.
But my question is 'how can I detect when it is a click on the string?'

Comment: Please show what have you already tried

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there isn't a simplistic way of doing this. Here are few things you can try (in decending order of accuracy and ascending order of compromise).

1. Break the span element by DOM manipulation into smaller one's each containing one word, or one letter depending how accurate you want it to be. Then add click listeners to each one of them.
2. If you are fine with word accuracy let the user double click instead of click which will lead to selecting the word and see what is selected by [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)
3. Grab the coordinates of the click and let's say the span has same font throughout with size of `z px` then the height and width of each letter will be more or less z pixels.

If you give some bigger picture of why do you want to do this we can come up with better solutions.

Here's implementation of 1st solution, using a 3rd party lib for sake of saving time. But I guess it would be better to write your implementaion because it would be slimmer.

```js
Splitting()[0].chars.forEach(charElem => {
  charElem.addEventListener("click", event => {
    console.log("clicked at", event.target.textContent, "at index", event.target.style.getPropertyValue("--char-index"));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>
<span data-splitting>foobar</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the cursorPosition

```
$('#text').on('click', function() {
    var cursorPos = $('#text').prop('selectionStart');
    console.log('click made after '+ cursorPos + ' characters');
});
```

Comment: Will only work for input, won't work for non-editable elements like span. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p31Lmj8w/)